# How to use IndexOf() method of List<object>

Tags: c#, list, indexof

All the examples I see of using the `IndexOf()` method in `List<T>` are of basic string types. What I want to know is how to return the index of a list type that is an object, based on one of the object variables.

```
List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
employeeList.Add(new Employee("First","Last",45.00));
```

I want to find the index where `employeeList.LastName == "Something"`

Comment: Is there a way to do this without lambda expressions? I'm stuck using .net 2.0

Comment: Can you use my solution below?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
int index = employeeList.FindIndex(employee => employee.LastName.Equals(somename, StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

Edit: Without lambdas for C# 2.0 (the original doesn't use LINQ or any .NET 3+ features, just the lambda syntax in C# 3.0):

```
int index = employeeList.FindIndex(
    delegate(Employee employee)
    {
        return employee.LastName.Equals(somename, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    });
```

Comment: I confirm this does the job. However the project doesn't use Linq. We are using .NET 2.0

Comment: @Bay: you can use the old (pre-C# 3) syntax for the anonymous delegates, but the original I wrote would work find in .NET 2 as long as you're compiling with the C# 3 compiler (C# 3.0 and .NET 3.0 are not dependent on each other).

Answer (score 26):

```
public int FindIndex(Predicate<T> match);
```

Using lambdas:

```
employeeList.FindIndex(r => r.LastName.Equals("Something"));
```

Note:

```
// Returns:
//     The zero-based index of the first occurrence of an element
//     that matches the conditions defined by match, if found; 
//     otherwise, –1.
```

Answer (score 13):

you can do this through override Equals method

```
class Employee
    {
        string _name;
        string _last;
        double _val;
        public Employee(string name, string last, double  val)
        {
            _name = name;
            _last = last;
            _val = val;
        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            Employee e = obj as Employee;
            return e._name == _name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the one we used to do in the fisrt dotnet version

Comment: This is actually the only answer that answers the original question - how to use `IndexOf()` with any object. Everyone else has just suggested using `FindIndex()` instead ... which is OK, but this answer should get more credit I think.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, one more for good measure :)

```
int index = employees.FindIndex(
      delegate(Employee employee)
        {
           return employee.LastName == "Something";
        });
```

Edit: - Full Example in .NET 2.0 Project.

```
class Program
{
    class Employee { public string LastName { get; set; } }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
        employeeList.Add(new Employee(){LastName="Something"});
        employeeList.Add(new Employee(){LastName="Something Else"});
        int index = employeeList.FindIndex(delegate(Employee employee) 
                           { return employee.LastName.Equals("Something"); });
        Console.WriteLine("Index:{0}", index);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this satisfies my actual request. I am leaving the check mark on the lambda version for other users as they might be using 3.5. Thanks.

Comment: Your example uses the initializer syntax that's only in C# 3. The OP hasn't clearly distinguished whether he's using C# 3 or C# 2, so it's hard to tell what he wants.

Answer (score 2):

> The answer is for those coming here to know why `IndexOf()`
>   doesn't work.

Your class must *override* `Equals` method of `object` possessing the following declaration.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer like this

```
    private List<Person> persons = List<Person>();

            public PersonService()
            {
                persons = new List<Person>() { 
                    new Person { Id = 1, DOB = DateTime.Today, FirstName = "Pawan", LastName = "Shakya" },
                    new Person { Id = 2, DOB = DateTime.Today, FirstName = "Bibek", LastName = "Pandey" },
                    new Person { Id = 3, DOB = DateTime.Today, FirstName = "Shrestha", LastName = "Prami" },
                    new Person { Id = 4, DOB = DateTime.Today, FirstName = "Monika", LastName = "Pandey" },
                };
            }

public PersonRepository.Interface.Person GetPerson(string lastName)
        {
            return persons[persons.FindIndex(p=>p.LastName.Equals(lastName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))];
        }
```