# how do i get index of an object in a custom class?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to an indexof method for a class that represents a list of objects.I would like to know the best approach. below is the code that I've come up with.

```
public int IndexOf(Product product)
    {

            Product p;
            for (int i = 0; i < products.Count; i++)
            {
                p = products[i];

                if (p == product)
                    return i;
            }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Is `products` a `List<Product>`? What's the type of `products`?

Comment: yes, its a list of type product

Comment: I was writing the answer, but seems someone give you first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If products is of type `List<Product>` you can just use the [`IndexOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb.aspx) method of your collection:

```
public int IndexOf(Product product)
{
   return products.IndexOf(product);
}
```

Comment: You beat me by 20 seconds, I had to check if IList<T> actually had this method ;)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get .IndexOf() working for my problem, but I found the following solution worked a treat.

[How to use IndexOf() method of List<object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568593/how-to-use-indexof-method-of-listobject)