# Finding the IndexOf deserialized json value in a list

Tags: json, list, restsharp, broadsign, dooh

I am trying to find the IndexOf in a list using a value as reference. Like lets say Id = 23144, I want the index when entering the Id.
This Object list is made by deserializing a Json retrieved with RestSharp.

```
{  
   "not_modified_since":"2018-06-05T22:22:18Z",
   "host":[  
      {  
         "active":true,
         "config_profile_bag_id":0,
         "container_id":0,
         "db_pickup_tm_utc":"2018-01-11T10:12:55",
         "discovery_status":0,
         "display_unit_id":0,
         "domain_id":103947039,
         "geolocation":"(0,0)",
         "id":195392183,
         "license_end_date":null,
         "licensed":true,
         "name":"Broadsign Services - Mathias - 16x64",
         "nscreens":0,
         "primary_mac_address":"00:0c:29:e0:e6:22",
         "public_key_fingerprint":"Redacted",
         "remote_clear_db_tm_utc":"1970-01-01T00:00:00",
         "remote_reboot_tm_utc":"2017-12-12T10:17:23",
         "secondary_mac_address":"",
         "volume":-1
      }
   ]
}
```

I have the following code:

```
private void bRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var client = new RestClient(endPoint);
    var request = new RestRequest("/host/v14/by_id", Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + key);
    request.AddParameter("domain_id", "103947039");
    request.AddParameter("ids", "195392183");
    request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    var response = client.Execute<RootObject>(request);
    var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content);
    var hosts = rootObject.Host;
    oResponse.Text = hosts.IndexOf();
}
```

There could be multiple host, so I'd like to be able to find the index of each host so I can then know which one to retrieve the value of following certain conditions, for example those that match the Id. In Sum I'd like to be able to know that id 195392183 is at index 0 so that I can then use that index to retrieve the value for name ( Broadsign Services - Mathias - 16x64 ) for example.

EDIT!
SOLVED! This worked for me:

```
var index = rootObject.Host.FindIndex(host => host.Id == 195392183);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the index of each host"? It's not clear what "shape" of result you want. A simple LINQ query should do the trick when we know what you want.

Comment: [How to use IndexOf() method of List<object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568593/how-to-use-indexof-method-of-listobject): `hosts.IndexOf(h => h.Id == "195392183")`?

Comment: The Rest response return a json that has a list separated by "host", so each of those host have their own elements and will have an index, if I understood well. I want the Index so that I can select the proper list.

Of course, if you have another way to achieving my end goal, I'm all ears. This is just the way I conceived it would work.

Comment: You should create a dictionary based on the Host objects and use Id property as the key. Then you can get the hosts by an Id like `hostsDict[Id]` or check if the key exists `hostsDict.ContainsKey(Id)`

Comment: Simple linq query would work for you. you don't need `IndexOf`. For example `hosts.Where(h => h.Id == 195392183).Select(h => h.Name)` would give you the name you require

Comment: @CodeCaster Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Host' because it is not a delegate type.

Comment: @Mathias read the linked question, my comment contains the wrong method (and I can't edit it anymore). It's `hosts.FindIndex(...)`.

Comment: This worked for me: `var index = rootObject.Host.FindIndex(host => host.Id == 195392183);`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary based on the Host

```
var hostsDict = rootObject.Select(r=> r.Host).ToDictionary<int, Host>(k=> k.Id, v=> v);

return hostDict[195392183];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an index to your deserialized object using a custom coverter.

```
public class ListWithIndexConverter<T> : JsonConverter where T : IIndexedObject
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(List<T>));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type != JTokenType.Array)
        {
            return new List<T>();
        }

        var returnList = new List<T>();
        for(var i=0; i < token.Count(); i++)
        {
            var returnObject = token[i].ToObject<T>();
            returnObject.Index = i;
            returnList.Add(returnObject);
        }
        return returnList;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public interface IIndexedObject
{
    int Index { get; set; }
}

public class SomeObject
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ListWithIndexConverter<Host>))]
    public List<Host> Hosts { get; set; }
}

public class Host : IIndexedObject
{
     //some properties
}
```